# Unable to play games in fullscreen on dual monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, fullscreen

I have an AMD Radeon HD 5700 series and 2 displays 1 24 inch samsung S24C300 and 1 Eizo EV2303W
I run windows 8.

When I try to play a game in full screen both the screens go black and nothing happends.
I have tried to change which is the primary display I also tried to phyiscly change the cables around in the back of my PC. I have made sure both the screens are running the same resolution.

Are there anyone who knows of a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your game's fullscreen resolution is probably set higher than that supported by your displays.

Try turning it down to a smaller resolution in the game's settings menu, either the total dimensions of your screens or else something really tiny to test it, like 1024x768 or 640x480.

Example: I have two monitors, next to each other. Both are of the resolution 1280x1024. Combined, their resolutions add to 2560x1024, so I'd enter that in my game's fullscreen resolution setting.

If your monitors are differently sized, then I don't know how windows handles them. My only computer with differently sized monitors runs debian linux, but it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found that it was not my dual monitor setup that was the problem, but my samsung s24c300 is not able to run games in full screen even if it is the only monitor connected to my computer (it goes black), so eighter there is something wrong with it or there is some setting that is not correct.